# What is Eta abstraction in lambda calculus used for?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Eta Abstraction in lambda calculus means following.

> A function `f` can be written as `\x -> f x`

- Is Eta abstraction of any use while reducing lambda expressions?
- Is it only an alternate way of writing certain expressions?

Practical use cases would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your evaluation strategy, eta conversion can be a useful way to delay evaluation

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to some link or example where there are some use cases of eta abstraction.

Comment: Under strict evaluation, eta abstraction could be used to implement the famous Y combinator. `Y := U (λh. λf. f (λx. h h f x))` where `U :=  λf. f f` — without `x` eta abstraction here, a strict evaluator would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: I think it's called eta *reduction*.

Comment: @盛安安 actually I believe it is called eta conversion. Not that it matters much.

Comment: Paraphrasing a quote from the [Eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) article in the Haskell wiki:"_Converting from `\x -> f x` to `f` would constitute an **eta reduction**, and moving in the opposite way would be an **eta abstraction**. The term **eta conversion** can refer to the process in either direction._"

Comment: @toraritte another term for it is eta expansion.

Comment: @WillNess thanks! I just came across that one half a minute ago:)

Comment: Related: [What's the point of η-conversion in lambda calculus?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/whats-the-point-of-eta-conversion-in-lambda-calculus)

Answer (score 7):

The eta reduction/expansion is just a consequence of the law that says that given

```
f = g
```

it must be, that for any x

```
f x = g x
```

and vice versa.

Hence given:

```
f x = (\y -> f y) x
```

we get, by beta reducing the right hand side

```
f x = f x
```

which must be true. Thus we can conclude

```
f   = \y -> f y
```

Answer (score 4):

First, to clarify the terminology, paraphrasing a quote from the [Eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) article in the Haskell wiki (also incorporating Will Ness' comment above):

> Converting from `\x -> f x` to `f` would
> constitute an **eta *reduction***, and moving in the opposite way
> would be an **eta *abstraction*** or ***expansion***. The term **eta *conversion*** can refer to the process in either direction.
>
> - Extensive use of η-reduction can lead to [Pointfree programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree).
> - It is also typically used in certain compile-time optimisations.

Summary of the use cases found:

1. Point-free (style of) programming
2. Allow lazy evaluation in languages using strict/eager evaluation strategies
3. Compile-time optimizations
4. Extensionality

### 1. Point-free (style of) programming

From the [Tacit programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) Wikipedia article:

> Tacit programming, also called point-free style, is a programming
> paradigm in which function definitions do not identify the arguments
> (or "points") on which they operate. Instead the definitions merely
> compose other functions

Borrowing a Haskell example from [sth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944540/1498178) (which also shows composition that I chose to ignore here):

```
inc x = x + 1
```

can be rewritten as

```
inc = (+) 1
```

This is because (following [yatima2975's reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794050/1498178)) `inc x = x + 1` is just syntactic sugar for `\x -> (+) 1 x` so

```
\x -> f       x   => f
\x -> ((+) 1) x   => (+) 1
```

(Check [Ingo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41814522/1498178) for the full proof.)

There is a [good thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670665/when-is-it-appropriate-to-choose-point-free-style-vs-a-data-centric-style-in-fun) on its usage. (See also [this repl.it snippet](https://repl.it/@toraritte/YoungWaterloggedWebsites).)

### 2. Allow lazy evaluation in languages using strict/eager evaluation strategies

Makes it possible to use lazy evaluation in eager/strict languages.

Paraphrasing from the MLton documentation on [Eta Expansion](http://mlton.org/EtaExpansion):

> Eta expansion delays the evaluation of `f` until the surrounding function/lambda is applied, and will re-evaluate `f` each time the function/lambda is applied.

Interesting Stackoverflow thread: [Can every functional language be lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766559/can-every-functional-language-be-lazy/)

#### 2.1 Thunks

I could be wrong, but I think the notion of *thunking* or *thunks* belongs here. From [the wikipedia article on thunks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk):

> In computer programming, a thunk is a subroutine used to inject an
> additional calculation into another subroutine. Thunks are primarily
> used to delay a calculation until its result is needed, or to insert
> operations at the beginning or end of the other subroutine.

The [4.2 Variations on a Scheme — Lazy Evaluation](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/4_002e2.xhtml) of the [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp) ([pdf](https://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf)) has a very detailed introduction to thunks (and even though the latter has not one occurrence of the phrase "lambda calculus", it is worth reading).

(This paper also seemed interesting but didn't have the time to look into it yet: [Thunks and the λ-Calculus](http://www.brics.dk/RS/96/19/BRICS-RS-96-19.pdf).)

### 3. Compile-time optimizations

Completely ignorant on this topic, therefore just presenting sources:

- From [Georg P. Loczewski's The Lambda Calculus](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/105/readings/loczewski.pdf):

  > In 'lazy' languages like Lambda Calculus, A++, SML, Haskell, Miranda etc., eta conversion, abstraction and reduction alike, are mainly used within compilers. (See [Jon87] page 22.)

  where `[Jon87]` expands to

  > Simon L. Peyton Jones
  > [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/the-implementation-of-functional-programming-languages/)
  > Prentice Hall International, Hertfordshire,HP2 7EZ, 1987.
  > ISBN 0 13 453325 9.
- [search results for `"eta" reduction abstraction expansion conversion "compiler" optimization`](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk030401qJdtpBnWYC6NYBVxvT1a1sA%3A1613418045636&ei=Pc4qYPelJtnA0PEPie2j-AI&q=%22eta%22%20reduction%20abstraction%20conversion%20expansion%20%22compiler%22%20optimization&oq=%22eta%22%20reduction%20abstraction%20conversion%20expansion%20%22compiler%22%20optimization&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECc6BwgAEEcQsANQnDhYjmVggGloAXACeACAAVuIAfwCkgEBNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi3uO_L0uzuAhVZIDQIHYn2CC8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5)

### 4. [Extensionality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality)

<sup>This is another topic that I know little about, and this is more theoretical, so here it goes:</sup>

From the [Lambda calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) wikipedia article:

> η-reduction expresses the idea of [extensionality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality), which in this context is that two functions are the same if and only if they give the same result for all arguments.

Some other sources:

- nLab entry on [Eta-conversion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/eta-conversion) that goes deeper into its connection with extensionality, and its relationship with [beta-conversion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/beta-conversion)
- ton of info in the [What's the point of η-conversion in lambda calculus?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/whats-the-point-of-eta-conversion-in-lambda-calculus) on the Theoretical Computer Science Stackexchange (but beware: the author of the accepted answer seems to have a beef with the commonly held belief about the relationsship between eta reduction and extensionality, so make sure to read the entire page. Most of it was over my head so I have no opinions.)
- The [question above has been cross-posted to Math Exchange as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65622/whats-the-point-of-eta-conversion-in-lambda-calculus)
- Speaking of "over my head" stuff: here's [Conor McBride's take](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-December/087850.html); the only thing I understood were that eta conversions can be controversial in certain context, but reading his reply was that of trying to figure out an alien language ([couldn't resist](https://youtu.be/NtEZqKHZ7es?t=85))

<sup>Saved this page recursively in Internet Archive so if any of the links are not live anymore then [that snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20211218151916/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617754/what-is-eta-abstraction-in-lambda-calculus-used-for) may have saved those too.</sup>

Comment: Now, *this*, ladies and gentlemen, is a good answer. Not only did you explain the uses, you straightened out the confusion about the terminology so we can clearly understand what you're talking about. Thanks—this was exactly what I needed to read right now.

Comment: Awww, you just made my day, thanks! Finally, my borderline OCD paid off:)