# Does the following Ramda/function programming pattern follow conventions/best practices?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Original

```
export const isTimeStrValid = str => {
  return str.length >= 4 && moment(str, ['H:mm', 'HH:mm'], true).isValid();
};
```

Ramda

```
export const isTimeStrValid = R.allPass([
  R.pipe(R.length, R.gte(R.__, 4)),
  R.pipe(
    s => moment(s, ['H:mm', 'HH:mm'], true),
    R.invoker(0, 'isValid'),
  ),
]);
```

The Ramda/functional programming version feels verbose but I can't quite figure out how to make it more elegant. As it stands, it appears that the original/imperative version is easier to read/understand. Does my Ramda version follow conventions/best practices?

Comment: Not strictly related but you may find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53670665/1244884) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I think your original function is fine. Since you're using ES6, you can get rid of the (imperative) `return` statement:

```
export const isTimeStrValid = str =>
  str.length >= 4 && moment(str, ['H:mm', 'HH:mm'], true).isValid();
```

Whether your "functional" version is ok from a best-practice perspective is hard to tell as this is mostly going to be a subjective debate.

The only thing I can tell, is that a point-free style *can* lead to verbosity, but you can mitigate that by splitting things into smaller chunks:

Would this read better to you for example?

```
const isTimeStrValid = R.both(isValidString, isValidMoment);
```

Where `isValidString` and `isValidMoment` are reusable functions:

```
const isValidString = R.compose(R.lte(4), R.length);
const toMoment = R.curry((strict, formats, datestr) => moment(datestr, formats, strict));
const isValidMoment = R.compose(R.invoker(0, 'isValid'), toMoment(true, ['H:mm', 'HH:mm']));
```

Comment: great answer. advice wrt _reusable functions_ is echoed :D

Comment: I concur.  Ramda is a library of functions that may be helpful.  It should never be a goal.

Comment: Note that `R.both` is often a reasonable alternative to `R.allPass`.  That is, `both(f, g)` reads better to me that `allPass([f, g])`.  But they do have slightly different APIs, with `allPass` guaranteeing a boolean and `both` returning false-y or truth-y answers.

Comment: I agree, `R.both` feels better in this case. I'll update.

Comment: I agree w/ @ScottSauyet Ramda doesn't need to be a goal. customcommander's reusable refactor is also a great alternative to point-free. And sometimes a mix of imperative does read better than pure declarative/functional, need to inspect and decide case-by-case. Thanks every one!