# Is it possible to implement a TypeScript generic version of Y-combinator?

Tags: typescript

The Y-combinator JavaScript implementation:

```js
const Y = g => (x => g(x(x)))(x => g(x(x)))
//or
const Y = f => {
  const g = x => f(x(x))
  return g(g)
}
```

I'm just curious, is it possible to implement a TypeScript generic version of Y-combinator?

```
type Y<F> = ???
```

Comment: It should be noted that this implementation of the Y combinator doesn't actually work (for any practical purpose) since javascript isn't lazily evaluated; it'll always recurse infinitely then error out once the stack limit has been reached. A more practical version is the Z combinator, which explicitly defines an argument, allowing the recursion to stop: `const Z = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))(x => f(v => x(x)(v)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:

**The TypeScript type of a fixed point combinator whose input is a one-argument function is:**

`type Y = <I, O>(F: (f: (i: I) => O) => ((i: I) => O)) => (i: I) => O;`

The long answer follows:

---

The type of a [fixed point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) should be a generic function of the following form:

```
type Fixed = <T>(f: (t: T) => T) => T;
```

So if you had a value `fixed` of type `Fixed`, you should be able to call it on any one argument function whose output is the same type as the input, and (magically?) get a result which is a fixed point of that function:

```
console.log(fixed(Math.cos)) // 0.739085...
```

You can get something like this behavior for certain well-behaved functions `f` just by starting with some random value and iterating `f` a bunch of times:

```
const fixed: Fixed = f => {
  let r = null as any;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) r = f(r);
  return r;
}
```

That's a silly implementation (or at least not the classic one) but it works well enough for the normal use case of finding a fixed point of a function whose input is itself a function.

For example, let's define a `protoFactorial` function whose fixed point calculates the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of a non-negative integer via recursion:

```
const protoFactorial = (f: (n: number) => number) =>
  (n: number) => n === 0 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)
```

Note that the input `f` is a function of type `(n: number) => number`, and the output is another function of this type, whose input `n` is the `n` is the number whose factorial we want to calculate.  If `n` is `0` it returns `1`; otherwise it returns `n * f(n - 1)`.

If we have a fixed point combinator `fixed`, we should be able to get the desired factorial function like so:

```
const factorial = fixed(protoFactorial);
console.log(factorial(7)); // 5040
```

And the above `fixed` does work for this.

---

But for the Y combinator in particular we tend to require that the type `T` on which it operates is itself a function type (although in untyped lambda calculus there's not really a distinction), and therefore I'd be inclined to give `Y` a generic type that specifically depends on the input and output of the `T` function type:

```
type Y = <I, O>(F: (f: (i: I) => O) => ((i: I) => O)) => (i: I) => O;
```

That is like `Fixed` if you replace `T` with `(i: I) => O`.  Anyway, with a value `Y` of type `Y`, we should presumably be able to call `Y(protoFactorial)` and get the correct `factorial`.

Here's an implementation of `Y` in TypeScript:

```
interface Ω<T> {
  (x: Ω<T>): T;
}

const Y: Y = <I, O>(F: (f: (i: I) => O) => (i: I) => O) =>
  ((x: Ω<(i: I) => O>) => F(x(x)))((x: Ω<(i: I) => O>) => F(x(x)));
```

Note that in order to strongly type the Y combinator implementation we need the recursive type `Ω<T>`; the `x` parameter has to be of such a type in order to allow a call like `x(x)` to compile and produce an output of type `(i: I) => O`.

This is the same as your `g => (x => g(x(x)))(x => g(x(x)))` implementation with `g` renamed to `F` and with type annotations to help the compiler.

---

That's the answer to the question as asked, but unfortunately the `Y` combinator cannot be used as-is in JavaScript, which eagerly evaluates all function inputs before evaluating the function body:

```
try {
  const factorial = Y(protoFactorial);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // too much recursion
}
```

Oops, calling `Y(protoFactorial)` eagerly expands out to the unending  `F(F(F(F(F(F(....` and explodes.

---

To get a viable fixed-point combinator in JavaScript, we need something more like the [Z combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Strict_fixed-point_combinator) which delays the calculation of `x(x)` by using eta abtraction (see [What is Eta abstraction in lambda calculus used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617754/what-is-eta-abstraction-in-lambda-calculus-used-for)) to produce `v => x(x)(v)`:

```
const Z: Y = <I, O>(F: (f: (i: I) => O) => (i: I) => O) =>
  ((x: Ω<(i: I) => O>) => F(v => x(x)(v)))((x: Ω<(i: I) => O>) => F(v => x(x)(v)));
```

Now if we use `Z` in place of `Y` it works at runtime:

```
const factorial = Z(protoFactorial);
// const factorial: (i: number) => number
console.log(factorial(7)); // 5040
```

---

Of course, if all we care about are the typings and we are don't need to pretend that JavaScript and TypeScript lack first-class recursion at runtime, then we can just implement a function of type `Y` recursively with a lot less hassle:

```
const R: Y = f => f(x => R(f)(x))    
console.log(R(protoFactorial)(7)) // 5040
```

---

From the perspective of the type system, all of `fixed`, `Y`, `Z`, and `R` are values of type `Y`:

```
function acceptY(y: Y) { }
acceptY(fixed)
acceptY(Y)
acceptY(Z)
acceptY(R)
```

And so we can say fairly confidently that the TypeScript type of a fixed point combinator whose input is a one-argument function is:

```
type Y = <I, O>(F: (f: (i: I) => O) => ((i: I) => O)) => (i: I) => O;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgSwB5QCYwLwwDwBUB8AFAGYBcMhI5uAlJvjLfYwNzDADGA9gHYDOIGMWRpyiFOizFmAb2AwYAGyiCATphg8ArosUwAhnwM8wbBcS7rCywQg0AGFjDvYYARnuenCANQ+66lKEqjRmMKoqWqo84WwAvuzc-FzKAHSKXADmJCKohACy+iAAFqncfDR0APRVMPapAOwAzACc9gAcAKypPYm8AjAQqlwgXHD6HKOqCPp6WCTkhDzk2gC2AEZQIcxrm9sY+PIUy5paG1t0B5qYGFj2MAD87jArMABUQkswALTuNOw8fSrKB8CATWDiNAwORHJIDYgTKYzOZCXKEIYjMaIyzI0Kw-opKDpLIkbHTWaEBqVJw1GCdewAFnswASoEgsAAmhpsABJAA0MAA8kQ4IsyBQEOQeZcGIKZRRCJKYNLmHL5YqpfLBWxgAgeCAtgiOLBAJXAeAYcgUhCQ5DNBBo1HifX4gg55C5WF5AuFhFFFHFGuVWvVSpVVzl9COhGttuwgbDsvw8rg1utlRo0ZtMDN8a1SeYKaQaep7BAqjA0PxLqEZORGg56OGo3GkxxszxcRgHCKHGKFCgdEtXYJaQy2QHNNqoy4MFWWl74SgHCifAQvBZzoGAC13dz+UKRWLFqHg8xc6qZVGY9m4yfVfmrimAG7MItIDNP9OZ2Pn8MPhjPq+aaEJ+JacP0ghGkiswaFujaYi20GKHicKEsS2RQW2iiUtSMC0vSTKboIABKu5SMwxDWswxEkBm77-OBySjiSNEYs2tbtjh1S1ARzLsMQWg8JMa4xBMxoQCADZgO6g4wAkYlQBJDbCBI-wKUphAcmpHDiZJhBbtpukNsR-xAA)